# Convert Gridview to Datatable using JQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridview, datatable

I am trying to convert a grid view to DataTable using javascript or JQuery. Can some on please help with this request. Please note that i cannot use AJAX due to server limitation. Please note that i have template fields and bound fields as the gridcolumns.

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdcloneProgoffers" runat="server" CssClass="mGrid" Width="98%" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    Visible="true" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Offerid" Visible="false">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblOfferId" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("OFFER_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Offer Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblOfferName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("OFFER_NAME") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PS-R" HeaderStyle-Width="5%">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblPreSelected" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("PRE_SELECTED_REQ") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PS-O" HeaderStyle-Width="5%">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblPreSelectedNot" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("PRE_SELECTED_NOT_REQ") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="O">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblOptional" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("OPTIONAL") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Eligibility_GM" HeaderText="Eligibility GM" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Eligibility_EE" HeaderText="Eligibility EE" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Eligibility_WD" HeaderText="Eligibility WD" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Eligibility_MDUBULK" HeaderText="Eligibility MDUBULK" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SERVICE_CODE" HeaderText="Service Code" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PRICE_CODE" HeaderText="Price Code" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="OFFER_STATE" HeaderText="Staged State" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Compliance_GM" HeaderText="Compliance GM" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Compliance_EE" HeaderText="Compliance EE" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Compliance_WD" HeaderText="Compliance WD" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Compliance_MDUBULK" HeaderText="Compliance MDUBULK" />
        <%-- <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Tags">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lbltags" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                               </asp:TemplateField>--%>
    </Columns>
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="header" Height="20px" />
```

Comment: Which kind of DataTable are you referring to? The datatables.net (http://datatables.net) one?

Comment: Hi lcarus, Yes i am referring to datatables used in C# .net.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer to my question above is still not very clear so I'll just answer the 2 things that you may be asking here:

GridViews and DataTables (the .NET ones) are not "convertible" because they serve different purposes. A GridView may use the data in a [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) to display it on the screen. For Example, you may do this:

```
DataTable dt = GetDataFromDataBase();
GridView.DataSource=dt; // dt contains rows coming from the database
GridView.DataBind(); //Gridview takes the rows from the datatable and creates a nice HTML table for displaying purposes, applying css, etc.
```

If you are referring to the [datatables plugin](http://www.datatables.net/) (the one I referred on my question to this post), then all you need to do is this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    grdcloneProgoffers.PreRender += new EventHandler(grdcloneProgoffers_PreRender);
}

void grdcloneProgoffers_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (grdcloneProgoffers.Rows.Count > 0)
  {
    grdcloneProgoffers.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
    grdcloneProgoffers.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
   }
}
```

What the above piece of code does is that it forces the GridView to draw THEAD and TBODY sections in the HTML table generated since the [datatables](http://www.datatables.net/) plugin requires these elements to be present.

After you do that, you simply have to do this on the javascript side:

```
$(function(){

    $('#<%=grdcloneProgoffers.ClientID%>').dataTable();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply lcarus. The reason i asked for this is because i have a scenario where in i need to load the griview on a Jquery pop up window and perform some updates to gridview. After all the operations are done i want bind the gridview1 to gridview2 on the button click that is on popup. Can you please tell me if i can copy the data from one gridview and bind it to other?

Comment: If the updates to the GridView in the pop-up window are all happening on the client-side and you expect to click the "Update" button to submit the changes to the server, you could persist the changes to the database at that point, get the fresh data again from the database and bind it to the original gridview again to display the updates. I can think of at least one more way to do this but there's no room to explain here. Unfortunately your question is still too broad. Good luck!